# place the MySQL libraries in the correct location

Tags: bash, mysql

Run the following command to place the MySQL libraries in the correct location:

```
cp /usr/local/mysql/lib/* /usr/local/lib/
```

and I get

`bash-3.2# cp /usr/local/mysql/lib/* /usr/local/lib/
cp: /usr/local/mysql/lib/mecab is a directory (not copied).
cp: /usr/local/mysql/lib/pkgconfig is a directory (not copied).
cp: /usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin is a directory (not copied).`

what is the reason of (Not Copied) and How can I Copy this command ?

Answer (score 1):

Directories within source **lib** folder need to be copied recoursively (with **-r** option)

```
cp -r /usr/local/mysql/lib/* /usr/local/lib/
```